# Python - Classes and objects

Tags: python-2.7

This may appear like a very trivial question but I have just started learning python classes and objects. I have a code like below.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
            self.x = float(x)
            self.y = float(y)
    def __str__(self):
            return '('+str(self.x)+','+str(self.y)+')'

def main():
p1 = Point(pt1,pt2)
p2 = Point(pt3,pt4)
p3 = Point(pt5,pt6)
p4 = Point(pt7,pt8)
parray = [p1,p2,p3,p4]
print " Points are", p1,p2,p3,p4
print "parray",parray
```

I m getting the below Output :

Points are (4.0,2.0) (4.0,8.0) (4.0,-1.0) (100.0,1.0)
parray - intersection.Point object at 0x7ff09f00a550, intersection.Point object at 0x7ff09f00a410, intersection.Point object at 0x7ff09f00a590

My question is why are the addresses of objects assigned to array while I get the values while printing the objects?
Can someone suggest a way to get the values returned by class in array in main function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `print` an object as an individual argument to a `print` statement in Python 2 or the `print()` function in Python 3, Python calls `str` on the object before printing it out.

When you put the object inside a container like a list and `print` the list, the list gets `str` called on it, but it in turn calls `repr` on each of the items it contains, rather than `str`. To understand why, look at the list `[1, '2, 3', 4]` and imagine what it would look like if the quotation marks were not included in the output when it was printed. The quotation marks are part of the `'2, 3'` string's `repr`.

So to make your class work the way you want, either rename your `__str__` method to `__repr__` (which will also work for `str` calls, since the default implementation of `__str__` is to call `__repr__`), or add an additional `__repr__` method. Sometimes it's useful to have a `__repr__` that returns a less ambiguous string than `__str__` does (for instance, it might name the class as well as the arguments). One common convention is to make `__repr__` return a string that could be `eval`ed to get an equivalent object again. For your class, that could look like:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "{}({!r}, {!r})".format(type(self).__name__, self.x, self.y)
```

I'd also recommend using string formatting like this (or the older `%s` style if you prefer), rather than concatenating lots of strings together to build your result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it so well!

Comment: Glad it helped. I edited to fix some typos, and while I was at it ended up adding some more expiation and even some example code, so make sure you check out the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Python containers, e.g. lists use an objects `__repr__` method when printing their contents, not their `__str__`,  Define `__repr__` instead:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '('+str(self.x)+','+str(self.y)+')'
```

If you want a more detailed explanation of `__repr__` vs `__str__` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for the input! @Blckknght